# Need to only return non-empty array values after preg_split

Tags: php, arrays

I am returning content that is entered into a textarea separated by linebreaks, like so:

```
06/10/2014 
06/11/2014
```

However, I want to avoid the fact that if a user should enter it in this way in the textbox(too many breaks leaves an empty space):

```
06/10/2014


06/11/2014
```

I would like to account for that, yet still only return the two date values and not an extra line break. The array looks like this if returning the second example:

PHP Code

```
$date_array = preg_split("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", $row['blackout_date'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
            // check for any extra returns or white spaces
            print_r($date_array);
```

ARRAY

```
Array ( [0] => 06/11/2014
[1] => 
[2] => 06/12/2014 )
```

I want to get rid of that empty array, but array_filter does NOT work. Any suggestions? Thanks!

Comment: Great manual at php.net: `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` maybe?

Comment: tried that too! no luck, but good idea.

Comment: Really? http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/ee25102e3a78fa845e823aee214e974994a1fc09

Comment: Well dang it works for you, but it isn't working for me on my Wordpress site... I am using a foreach loop to iterate through a custom field. Maybe that is causing an issue?

Comment: I found that it was a Wordpress formatting issue in Advanced Custom Fields converting new lines to <br /> tags. I selected to have no formatting chosen and all my problems went away. Thanks everyone! I chose the correct answer, which was the PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY parameter. I think that works, but is my regex not right someone said??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[preg_split()](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-split.php) with `\r\n pattern` can be used to fix your issue.

```
$date_array = preg_split('/[\r\n]+/', $row['blackout_date'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

Comment: SO thanks you for your answer, but it has been posted for review because of quality issues. While your answer may be right, there is no explanation as to why, and what the OP did wrong. While code only answers are generally discouraged, I'm not going to recommend this for deletion as it does appear to be helpful.

Comment: @EngineerDollery, thank you for pointing out me the mistake. Anyways i have an updated answer. :)

Comment: what's your regex pattern do that mine doesn't?

Answer (score 1):

Just use [`array_filter`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) like this to get rid of the empty array values:

```
// Set the test data.
$test_data = <<<EOT
06/10/2014


06/11/2014
EOT;

// Check for any extra returns or white spaces.
$date_array = preg_split("/(\r\n|\r|\n)/", $test_data, -1);

// Use 'array_filer' and 'array_values' to shake out the date array.
$date_array = array_values(array_filter($date_array));

// Check the cleaned date array by dumping the data.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($date_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

The output would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06/10/2014
    [1] => 06/11/2014
)
```

Or how about attacking the empty lines issue another way: Maybe you should just use [`preg_match_all`](http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.preg-match-all.php) to match the actual dates you want instead of splitting with [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php)?

```
// Set the test data.
$test_data = <<<EOT
06/10/2014


06/11/2014
EOT;

// Match all of the dates that match your format.
preg_match_all('/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{4}/is', $test_data, $matches);

// Set the date array based on the dates matched.
$date_array = array_values(array_filter($matches[0]));

// Check the cleaned date array by dumping the data.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($date_array);
echo '</pre>';
```

And the output of that would be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 06/10/2014
    [1] => 06/11/2014
)
```

Comment: But I already tried array_filter. Note what I said in original post :) It still produces the empty array above... makes me wonder what is actually being returned if it isn't null or "".

Answer (score 1):

The way the precedence works in the alternation `|` in the pattern may leave stray `\n` or `\r` that is not considered empty.  Try:

```
$date_array = preg_split("/\s+/", $row['blackout_date'], -1, PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
```

In this case `PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY` is probably not needed, but I left it to be safe.

Comment: very helpful, although I found that it was a Wordpress formatting issue in Advanced Custom Fields converting new lines to <br /> tags. I selected to have no formatting chosen and all my problems went away. Thanks man!